# Sorting of Arraylist of Custom Object in java

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I have a Custom Object Suppose `Team`

```
public class Team{
    String      name;
    int         teamNo;
    ArrayList<Team> innerTeams;
    int teamId;

    //Getters and Setter Methods
```

Now I want to Sort it in Ascending Order of First Property **`name`**  taking into account that each **`Team`** Object has a property of itself as `Team` as `arraylist` declared as `innerTeams`  How can I be able to Sort this. So utlimately when any `arrayList` of object `Team` is present it should be sorted.

Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property?rq=1

Comment: sort the top array list then the inner ones (something like that)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to sort a `List` of `Team` objects based on their `innerTeams`? Seems like if you're comparing `Team` objects you would compare by name.

Comment: @D.B. Infact I'm trying to Sort the List of `Team` by its `name`. Bu then Since it has `innerTeam` as an Property I want the `innerTeam` also to be sorted.

Comment: @JohnHumanyun in that case see [the answer by SergeyB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46607948/3284624). Implementing `Comparable` allows you to sort any `List` of `Team` objects. If you want the `innerTeams` to be sorted then your `Team` class should handle sorting it as needed based on your requirements - for example sort it when returning it in a getter method, etc. The `Team` class would call the `Collections.sort` method internally in order to take advantage of its own `compareTo` method. E.g. `public List<Team> getInnerTeams(){ Collections.sort(innerTeams); return innerTeams;}`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have your `Team` class implement `Comparable`. You can tweak the logic inside of the `compareTo` to match your needs, e.g. compare inner team names, etc. Then you use `Collections.sort()` to do the actual sorting.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Team implements Comparable<Team> {

    String name;
    int teamNo;
    List<Team> innerTeams = new ArrayList<>();
    int teamId;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Team o) {
        if(o == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if(name == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return name.compareTo(o.name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Team team1 = new Team();
        team1.name = "z";
        Team team2 = new Team();
        team2.name = "a";

        List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        teams.add(team1);
        teams.add(team2);

        System.out.println(teams);

        Collections.sort(teams);

        System.out.println(teams);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[z, a]
[a, z]
```

You can then also use the same approach to sort innerTeams by name if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should define Comparator of Team.

```
class TeamComparator implements Comparator<Team>{
  public int compare(Team o1,Team o2){ 
    return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);  
  }
}
```

And sort by Collections.sort(teamList, new TeamComparator())

Comment: `o1.name` assumes `o1` is not null and similarly `o2.name` assumes `o2` is not null.